# including links not working in jquery getJSON post

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, hyperlink

When I issue the following command:

```
var msg = 'http://link.com';
var url = localPath + 'app/messages/save?msg='+encodeURIComponent(msg);
jQuery.getJSON(url,function(){});
```

It's not saving in my PHP to MySQL backend code.

It seems to only have this problem with using links.

When I do this it's fine:

```
var msg = 'Hey Bob!';
var url = localPath + 'app/messages/save?msg='+encodeURIComponent(msg);
jQuery.getJSON(url,function(){});
```

Comment: when you use msg=http://link.com ,it collapse with localPath variable @jkushner

Comment: @sany2k8 i dont understand what you are saying. can you solve the issue in an answer?

Comment: i just point, what is your localPath variable?, is it contains 'http://' or any other string like 'Hey Bob!'

Comment: @sany2k8 its just a variable that contains the url for me to use depending on what environment im on. its not important. what is important is that i cannot pass a link through ajax using jquery to my php backend and have that be saved in the database

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to send link to server side using jquery getJson method, code is not tested.

```
var url = "http://www.link.com/"

//if it is a url string escape it
if (url.split("http://").length > 1) 
{ 
    var mydata=escape(url);
}
else 
{
    var mydata=url; //if not string no need to escape it
}

 $.getJSON('http://address.com/messages.php', { url:mydata }, function(data) {
    // other code here
 });

  OR

 $.getJSON('http://address.com/message.php?url='+mydata, function(data) {
    // some code here
 });
```

Finally access it in messgages.php using  `$mydata = $_GET['mydata']` or

$_REQUEST['mydata'];

Comment: Now I am thinking about using escape, however sometimes the message is not a url so then i should be using encodeURIComponent? Can you update your question to handle the logic of whether its a url or not?

Comment: sorry for late response @jkushner